# Download and extract tar file from s3 to azure file share - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

i have few `tar` files in a `S3 bucket`  i would like to download them and extract them to a `azurefileshare` using `terraform`. In this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/archive/d/archive_file.html), i can see that `zip` is only supported. Is this right? And also i dont see any docs for extracting `files` any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use Terraform for this?

Comment: Just wanted to see if it works, should i use `ansible` for this? and have that layer in `terraform`?

Comment: Is this part of something much larger or is it a one off activity?

Comment: through `terraform` i will be spinning up some servers and need to copy these `files`, wanted no other code.